# Laravel5.7 routing using Route:match not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authentication, laravel-routing

I'm using Laravel 5.7 I'm trying to route my function for get and post.
I want to load a view and post a form.
As I have studied

```
Route::match(['GET','POST'], '/', TestController@test);
Route::any('/', TestController@test);`
```

one of these should work.

**But its not working for me,is there any other way or I'm doing something wrong?**

> UPDATE

Route to admin:

```
Route::match(['get','post'], 'cp/', 'AdminController@test');
```

**Function in Admin controller:**

```
public function test( Request $request){

    $data=array();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        echo "here it is";
        exit;
    }else{ 
        echo "still in get!";
    }
    return view('admin/login',  $data);
}
```

And my view in short is something like this:

```
<form  action="{{ url('/cp') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<form>
```

Comment: Did you have some error ? 
And can you show us TestController ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, every time I post my form  `Request::method()` always returns GET, never execute this code`if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {}`

Comment: only works when I define separate route to post.

Comment: @Saromase I get no errors whenever i submit my form it goes to "Get" code. If I make a post route the same code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try changing

```
Route::match(['GET','POST'], '/', TestController@test);
```

to

```
Route::match(['GET','POST'], '/', 'TestController@test');
```

OR

```
Route::any('/', TestController@test);
```

to

```
Route::any('/', 'TestController@test');
```

The second param should be wrapped in quotes!

**UPDATE:**

Your route match code should be something like this :

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST', 'PUT'), "/", array(
    'uses' => 'Controller@index',
    'as' => 'index'
));
```

Comment: Well,I tried this but it still goes in get! @iftikhar

Comment: @SaniaIshaq can you share the full code please? View where form is! + Controller and Routes!

Comment: Ok for routing its: `Route::match(['get','post'], 'cp/', 'AdminController@test');`

Comment: For my test function its something like : ` public function test( Request $request){
        $data=array();
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            echo "here it is";
            exit;
        }else{
            echo "still in get!";

        }
        return view('admin/login',  $data);
    }`

Comment: for form its simple input form with post as method.

Comment: Your form action is set to which route?

Comment: `<form  action="{{ url('/cp') }}" method="POST">`

Comment: Please share the full code so that i can debug it properly!

Comment: Share the code in question. You can edit your question!

Comment: Updated,please check

Comment: @SaniaIshaq change `Route::match(['get','post'], 'cp/', 'AdminController@test');` to `Route::match(['get','post'], '/cp', 'AdminController@test');`

Comment: If still the issue isn't solved can you share your teamviewer details so that i can debug the issue in your PC!

Comment: I don't see any change in the statement.its same as mine.

Comment: @SaniaIshaq you are doing `cp/` and new one should be `/cp`

Comment: I understand the slash was what you updated but its same,no changes.its still going to 'GET'

Comment: @SaniaIshaq do you have teamviewer ? Pass ID and username here!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in you `web.php`

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/testMethods', function () 
{
    dd('its workong bro');
});
```

And hit the `yourprojectname/testMethods`  in your web browser

Eg: `http://localhost:8000/testMethods`

From `Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Registrar.php`

```
public function match($methods, $uri, $action);
```

Here is match function parameter list

> Parameter One   List of methods: Eg: get,post,put,patch
>
> Parameter two   url : Eg: /testMethods
>
> Parameter three Method: Eg: TestController@test

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/testMethods','TestController@test');
```

Comment: This should be a comment!

Answer (score 0):

Well, by the end what I understand to use `route::match` I should specify function name without it it will not work.So when I changed it to `Route::match(array('GET', 'POST', 'PUT'), "/login", array(
    'uses' => 'AdminController@login',
    'as' => 'login'
));`
It resolves the issue. Thank for the help everyone!!